# array of objects inside NSDictionary in JSON response - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to obtain a list of objects from `NSDictionary`'s JSON response then store it in `NSMutableArray` but it keeps giving me only one object in the array, Can you help me with a sample code please,

Here is the json response:

```
{
  "errorCd": "00",
  "desc": "Success",
  "ref": 83,
  "statusCode": "1",
  "extraData": [
    {
      "key": "bal",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "key": "txs",
      "value": "[{\"id\":2268099999,\"amnt\":100.0,\"curr\":\"JOD\",\"sender\":\"PSPCI\",\"receiver\":\"00962799999992\",\"date\":\"Feb 1, 2016 4:03:25 PM\",\"status\":1,\"type\":5,\"fees\":0.0,\"reference\":40},{\"id\":2357099999,\"amnt\":20.0,\"curr\":\"JOD\",\"sender\":\"00962799999992\",\"receiver\":\"PSPCI\",\"date\":\"Feb 2, 2016 12:52:35 PM\",\"status\":1,\"type\":6,\"fees\":0.0,\"reference\":68}]"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to obtain the list in the value for the key txs.

This is what am trying to do:

```
-(NSDictionary *)getListOfExtraData:(NSMutableArray *)extras{
    NSDictionary *array = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in extras) {
        if([[dictionary valueForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"txs"])
            array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"value"];
    }
    if (array != nil && array.count > 0)
        return array;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: According to the response the value looks like to be a string but not an array. I remember it has to be something like this ["A", "B"] without quotation mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would say that the JSON is unusual; it looks like it can be a stringified number (`"80"`) or a JSON array.

You need to further parse the inner array, with:

```
NSData *jsonResponse = ...;    // Response from server
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *topLevelDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse
                                                             options:0
                                                               error:&error];
if (topLevelDict) {
    NSArray *extraData = topLevelDict[@"extraData"];
    for (NSDictionary *innerDict in extraData) {
        if ([innerDict[@"key"] isEqualToString:@"txs"]) {
            NSString *valueStr = innerDict[@"value"];
            NSArray *innerArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[valueStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:&error];
            if (innerArray) {
                // FINALLY!  WE HAVE IT!
            } else {
                // Report error
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    // report error
}
```

Comment: This solution is worked like magic with me, thank you so much, the json response is right but the idea with the inner parsing for the array!
nice idea and thank you so much again

Answer (score 2):

The JSON data is invalid as `value` has an object inside `"`

You should send your JSON like this

```
{

  "errorCd": "00",
  "desc": "Success",
  "ref": 83,
  "statusCode": "1",
  "extraData": [
    {
      "key": "bal",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "key": "txs",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": 2268099999,
          "amnt": 100.0,
          "curr": "JOD",
          "sender": "PSPCI",
          "receiver": "00962799999992",
          "date": "Feb 1, 2016 4:03:25 PM",
          "status": 1,
          "type": 5,
          "fees": 0.0,
          "reference": 40
        },
        {
          "id": 2357099999,
          "amnt": 20.0,
          "curr": "JOD",
          "sender": "00962799999992",
          "receiver": "PSPCI",
          "date": "Feb 2, 2016 12:52:35 PM",
          "status": 1,
          "type": 6,
          "fees": 0.0,
          "reference": 68
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And what if the OP has no control over the JSON encoding?

Comment: The json object response is general to contain any key and value object and make use of the value to put any values we need objects or strings or array

Answer (score 0):

```
After the json is in correct format,i.e.


{
  "errorCd": "00",
  "desc": "Success",
  "ref": 83,
  "statusCode": "1",
  "extraData": [
    {
      "key": "bal",
      "value": "80"
    },
    {
      "key": "txs",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": 2268099999,
          "amnt": 100.0,
          "curr": "JOD",
          "sender": "PSPCI",
          "receiver": "00962799999992",
          "date": "Feb 1, 2016 4:03:25 PM",
          "status": 1,
          "type": 5,
          "fees": 0.0,
          "reference": 40
        },
        {
          "id": 2357099999,
          "amnt": 20.0,
          "curr": "JOD",
          "sender": "00962799999992",
          "receiver": "PSPCI",
          "date": "Feb 2, 2016 12:52:35 PM",
          "status": 1,
          "type": 6,
          "fees": 0.0,
          "reference": 68
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to store the array you need to declare the variable **array** as a NSArray or NSMutableArray and not NSDictionary